# Show that there exist infinitely many $x_{0} \in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x_{0} + \pi) = f(x_{0}).$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(x)=f(x+1), \forall x\in \Bbb R$. Then show that there exist infinitely many $x_{0} \in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x_{0} + \pi) = f(x_{0}).$

I found this question in a set of problems listed in a handout on real analysis.

Under these circumstances, my general strategy is to construct a function $g(x)=f(x+\pi)-f(x).$ If we can ensure a root of $g(x)$ then we are done. Since $f$ is further periodic with a period of $1$ so, we can consider or restrict the domain of $f$ to $[0,1].$ If I am able to find a root of $g$ in the interval $[0,1]$ then we are done. But I just can't find one root in this interval, or to put precisely, I dont *know how to find one.*

Once, I am able to find a root say $x_0$ then automatically I can assert that we have an infinite number of solutions for then $x_0+1$ also satisfies $f(x_{0} + \pi) = f(x_{0})$ since $f(x)=f(x+1), \forall x\in \Bbb R.$

I just need to find the root $x_0.$

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but using that g admits the  period $1$ you can say your g(x) is also $f(x+\pi)-f(x+k)$ for any integer $k.$ from that one maybe gets a sign change and cn apply intermediate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, $f$ is continuous over a bounded interval $[0,1]$ by Maximum-Minimum Theorem, we can claim that $\exists a,b\in [0,1]$ such that, $f$ attains it's maximum and minimum value at the points $a$ and $b$ respectively.

If $f(a)=f(b)$ then $f$ is a constant function and the claim in the problem is true.

Let $f(a)\neq f(b).$  If $f(a)=f(a+\pi)$ or $f(b)=f(b+\pi)$ then we are done, for then we have, $x_0=a$ or $x_0=b$ respectively, and $g(x_0)=0,$ where $x_0\in [0,1].$

Otherwise, since $f$ attains it's absolute maximum on $a$ we have, $f(a)-f(a+\pi)\gt 0.$ Similarly, since $f$ attains it's absolute minimum on $b$ we have, $f(b)-f(b+\pi)\lt 0$ as $f(b)\neq f(b+\pi).$

So, we have, $g(a)\lt 0$ and $g(b)\gt 0$. Finally, as $g$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ so, by Bolzano's Intermediate Value Theorem, we have, a number, $x_0$ in between $a$ and $b$ such that, $ g(x_0)=0.$ So, we have found a number $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that, $g(x_0)=0.$

Finally, since, we have found the existence of a root $x_0$ of $g$ when $f(a)\neq f(b)$ we can say, $\exists x_0\in [0,1]$ such that, $f(x_0)=f(x_0+\pi).$

Now, as $f$ is periodic in $\Bbb R$ so, there exists, infinitely many $x_0x_0\in [0,1]$ such that, $f(x_0)=f(x_0+\pi).$

Answer (score 5):

Suppose there is no such $x_0$. Then $g(x)$ cannot change signs. Suppose it always positive. Thus, $f(x+\pi)>f(x)$ for all $x$. Iteration and periodicity give  $f(x+n\pi+m)>f(x)$ for all integers $m$ and all positive integers $n$.  It is well known the numbers of the form $n\pi+m$ form a  dense set in $\mathbb R$. [True with $\pi$ replaced by any irrational number].

We now get (by continuity) $f(x+y) \geq f(x)$ for all $x,y$. This makes $f$ a  constant (in which case there is nothing to prove).